# IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added

Tags: android, firebase-performance

we are using firebase-perf plugin in our app, but while testing we are getting multiple instance of this error 
`IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added`

please find the log given below.

```
 Process: packageName, PID: 27378
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {packageName.Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4425)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added
        at android.view.View.removeFrameMetricsListener(View.java:6244)
        at android.view.Window.removeOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener(Window.java:889)
        at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:432)
        at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:245)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzd.onActivityStopped(Unknown Source:33)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStopped(Application.java:234)
        at android.app.Activity.onStop(Activity.java:1862)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:613)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1376)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7205)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4425) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

following the gradle dependencies we are using:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
```

Comment: Please file a bug report with Firebase support.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Thanks, already reported a week ago, but still no response from their side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf`.

Removing
    `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" from AndroidManifest.xml`

Or in your activity (from the crash's message) do the following:

```java
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try {
        super.onStop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onStop()", e);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```